# What does $this refer to in magento's actions?

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking at this file:

https://github.com/magentomirror/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.5/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php

what does:

```
$this
```

and

```
$this->
```

refer to?

Comment: How about `var_dump($this)`? Of course it refers to the current object of type class `Mage_Catalog_ProductController`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It refers to the object "`Mage_Catalog_ProductController`" in that case. "`$this`" refers to the current object, so it's relative to which class it's called from.

[PHP Manual for OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)